# Mysql query LIKE not working

Tags: wp-query, mysql, wpdb

I'm using this code.

```
$blog_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT " . $extra . "blog_id, last_updated FROM " . $wpdb->blogs. " WHERE public = '1' AND archived = '0' AND mature = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted ='0' AND UPPER(blog_name) LIKE 'A%'" . $order . " " . $limit . "", ARRAY_A );
```

But that LIKE statement `AND UPPER(blog_name) LIKE 'A%'"`  not working. Can anyone give me the solution?

Thanks

### Update:

Actually i'm using this code

```
$where = ''; 
if ($filter) { 
$where = "AND UPPER(blog_name) LIKE '".strtoupper($filter)."%' "; 
}
```

So i'll replace `AND UPPER(blog_name) LIKE 'A%'"` with `$where` later

Note: I have 500+ blogs in my network.

> I want to display all blog names with anchor link in a page. But I don't want to load all the blog names. So I'm trying to achieve alphabetical navigation. If the user click link "A" then the page should display Blog names starts with "A". Likewise B, C, etc.

Here is the [full code](http://pastebin.com/85Qx7Dzf) if anyone interested

Comment: Note: Get rid of the UPPER and the strtoupper. LIKE comparisons are case-insensitive in MySQL.

Comment: @Otto Thanks. But i dropped this idea. Because Kaiser said `The problem is that you will won't be able to search from the beginning of the string. So you'll get every blog that contains an A in it's name`. I'm trying [this one](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-anyone-help-me-to-list-all-the-blogs-in-a-page-with-alphabetic-navigation?replies=1) instead of querying mysql.  I'm trying to implement it for more than 20 hours  So please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: Umm.. No, "A%" will indeed find all the entries starting with A. If you wanted A anywhere in the string then you'd use "%A%" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Prepare your Queries!

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT %s blog_id, last_updated FROM %s WHERE public = '1' AND archived = '0' AND mature = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted ='0' AND UPPER(blog_name) LIKE '%s' %s %s ", ARRAY_A 
    ),
    $extra,
    $wpdb->blogs,
    $wpdb->esc_like( 'A%' ),
    $order,
    $limit
);
```

**Never ever send data without prepare!** Also: There're some functions like `like_escape()` that'll help you preparing the data properly.

*Still wondering why you'd want to search for something like `A%`…*

Comment: Could you please simply a) update your Q as the code is impossible to read in a comment and b) reply to @Brady answer? Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser I think he is trying to search for all blogs on his network starting with the letter A. A lot of his questions lately are related to multisite where he is running a network of lots of sub sites.

Comment: @Brady Yes you are right. I'm trying to create a alphabetical navigation. If the user click "A", i want to display only the blog names which starts with A. Like wise B,C,etc

Comment: @kaiser Updated my question

Comment: @Viruthagiri How about another update to the Q to reflect your _real Q_ »_I'm trying to create a alphabetical navigation. If the user click "A", i want to display only the blog names which starts with A. Like wise B,C,etc_«

Comment: Btw: The problem is that you will won't be able to search from the beginning of the string. So you'll get _every_ blog that contains an `A` in it's name.

Comment: @kaiser can you update the question title for me? I'm not sure how to create proper title. Thanks

Comment: The title is fine for me.

Comment: `The problem is that you will won't be able to search from the beginning of the string. So you'll get every blog that contains an A in it's name. ` Is there any other option available?

Comment: Yes: Go with what @Brady wrote.

Answer (score 1):

What @kaiser said plus:

In this table there is no blog_name field... It appears that your query includes some other SQL but without that we cannot tell whats going wrong.

[image: where is blog_name]

**Update**
The only place the blog name resides is in the individual blogs options table. So to do what you are after you would have to do this:

Read out all your blog ID's that are `public = 1 && achieved = 0 && mature = 0 && spam = 0 && deleted = 0`. That's one query there that in your case would return about 500 records. Then with each record you would have to read each blog options table `{prefix}_{ID}_options` and find the row that has a `option_name = 'blogname'` and then check if that record begins with the letter of choice.

Maybe the above is possible in one massive MySQL query but I'd hate to be the one to put it together.

I cannot help any further. If it was me looking to do what you are after I'd look at creating a new table of my own and keep it up to date with the info I need to search. I'd use available hooks to make sure that when a new site is added/updated/deleted it would update this table I had created.

Comment: Hi Brady, Please check this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/85Qx7Dzf)

Comment: @Viruthagiri - You are searching the blogs table on a column called 'blog_name' which doesn't exist in this table. You need to do some JOIN magic with other tables to pull in blog_name. But looking at the tables that are available there is no single table that contains all the blogs names.

Comment: Ah.. Can you give me some sample code? Please check this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fn4niFAa) too. This code doesn't contains that filter. So it returns all blog names

Comment: See update I have made

Comment: Thanks for the update. One last question. [Check this code](http://wordpress.pastebin.ca/1746118) Can i adapt that code to implement this feature or Should i go with the idea you updated. Which one is best?

Comment: Matter of personal opinion. I'd go with the solution I have outlined but there is a lot of work involved there to get a working solution.

Comment: I'd stick with @Brady recommendation: Do it in a stepped process for easier debugging +  Save your data to a separate table. Also: You should add another answer when you're done. There you should add your code for later readers and mark it as solution 2 days later.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks for the suggestion, But brady said it requires lot of work. I'm not a wordpress expert. So its highly impossible to do it by myself. [This code](http://wordpress.pastebin.ca/1746118) seems simple. So i'm gonna try it. When i achieve it i'll post my answer here.